# Levantar servicios windows cumpliendo 2 condiciones

Tags: batch

necesito mantener funcionando servicios de windows, solo exceptuando mientras se realizan trabajos de mantención, ya que es el único momento donde se define startup type=manual y se detiene el servicio.

Hasta el momento tengo este código, pero no logro detectar que el "startup type" sea diferente a "manual" para recién ejecutar el net start.

```
@echo off
net start | find "wuauserv" > nul 2>&1 
if not .%errorlevel%.==.0. net start "wuauserv"
```

Comment: Una solución sucia pero  pragmática es correr `net start` de todas maneras. Si ya estaba corriendo tirará un error que deberíamos ignorar.

Comment: En inglés: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325081/how-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-via-batch-file-and-start-it-if-it-is-not-r

Comment: @leonbloy precisamente quiere evitar dar un `start` a un servicio que han puesto temporalmente en arranque manual por tareas de mantenimiento.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes [usar `sc`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490995.aspx) para preguntar información de configuración (`qc`, query configuration) de un servicio:

> qc: Queries the configuration information for a service.
>
> qc: Consulta la información de configuración de un servicio.

Ejemplo de uso:

```
C:\Windows\system32>sc qc AppMgmt
[SC] QueryServiceConfig SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: AppMgmt
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        START_TYPE         : 3   DEMAND_START
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   :
        TAG                : 0
        DISPLAY_NAME       : Application Management
        DEPENDENCIES       :
        SERVICE_START_NAME : LocalSystem
```

Como puedes ver éste tiene arranque manual (`DEMAND_START`).

Ejemplo en el que compruebo el modo de arranque y el estado del servicio:

```
@echo off
sc qc %1 | find "AUTO_START" > NUL
if not errorlevel 0 goto fin

sc query %1 | find "STOPPED" > NUL
if not errorlevel 0 goto fin

echo Arrancando el servicio %1
sc start %1

:fin
echo Trabajo finalizado
```

Primero compruebo si es arranque automático (`AUTO_START`), en cualquier otro caso termino la ejecución.

Si es un servicio de arranque automático compruebo si está en estado parado (`STOPPED`), en cualquier otro caso termino la ejecución (ojo, podría estar en estado `PAUSED`, `PAUSE_PENDING`, `CONTINUE_PENDING`, `START_PENDING` o `STOP_PENDING`.

Al final, si el servicio está configurado para arranque automático y está parado, se le ordena el arranque.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su pronta respuesta estimado, el único problema que tengo es que extrañamente en algunos casos el servicio quedan en estado en blanco (derechamente no dice nada). Existirá alguna manera de poder incluir esto en su código ?

Comment: ¿Consultándolo con `sc`? Nunca me ha pasado. ¿Puedes copiar/pegar lo que te sale en el símbolo de sistema cuando te ocurre eso? (Preferiblemente como nota de tu pregunta, para que mantenga el formato)

Comment: ¿Ese caso que me comentas es al actualizar la aplicación? Es posible que durante el proceso el servicio se elimine y vuelva a crear. ¿Podrías darme más detalles de cuándo te pasa eso?